# Force seed data migration in between 2 migrations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have 2 migrations that I wish to run.

1. Create new table of currencies.
2. Link existing table to currencies with FK and update script.

```
Sql("UPDATE dbo.Rates" +
    " SET CurrencyId = c.Id" +
    " from Rates r" +
    " join Currencies c on c.IsoCode = r.CurrencyIso");
```

I also have seed data that populates the currencies table.

I need to be able to run migration 1, run the seed, then run migration 2 all in one hit.

How do I force the seed data into db before I reference the FK?

Comment: Is there a reason why it couldn't be 3 seprate migrations?

Comment: Not sure I understand how that will help matters? I need the seed to run between 2 migrations.